# Problems with Get-ADUser -Filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I want to know how many Users whose ending are two numbers there are where the Attribute "UserParameters" is null. This is my command so far:

```
$var1 = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "*[0-9][0-9]"} -SearchBase "OU=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xx" | Where-Object {$_.UserParameters -eq $null}
```

If I type in `$var1.count` it just replies with 0. Why is that so? And yes there are users that end with two numbers. I think the -Filter is the Problem because if I just type `-Filter *` it works just fine.
Please help me!

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to assign the outcome of Get-ADUser to your variable?. Also, `Filter` should be a string, not a scriptblock. I don't think the filter will understand `[0-9][0-9]`, so you'll have to use a Where-Object clause

Answer (score 1):

The AD Filter provider has no clue what the wildcard `[0-9]` means. You can construct an LDAP Filter yourself if needed which would essentianlly be an OR pattern `|`:

```
(|(samAccountName=*00)(samAccountName=*01)(samAccountName=*02)(samAccountName=*03)...)
```

For example:

```bash
$filter = "(|"
foreach($i in 0..9) {
    foreach($x in 0..9) {
        $filter += "(samAccountName=*$i$x)"
    }
}
$filter += ")"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase 'OU=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xx'
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but i'm really new to PowerShell and barely know to write a function. Can you please tell me how i can apply this function to my script or tell how I need to approach this because it all sounds greek to me.

Comment: @cosmo_ as explained in the answer, the filter `SamAccountName -like "*[0-9][0-9]"` is not valid for Active Directory you can however replace it by an OR pattern as shown in my answer. Im not sure what else there is to explain.